# WordPress url duplicates domain name

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

I built a site in WordPress, all works fine, but after uploading, all my links are reading wrongly.

My site name is nativemedialimited.com and thats what its supposed to read on the url, but when i click on any link in the menu, example, I get http://nativemedialimited.com/nativemedialimited.com/clip when i click on 'clip' hence this gives me 404 error.

I have eddited the options parameter in the database for site url and home. I have done all that I would do normally as this is not my first WordPress upload.

Thanks ahead

Comment: Can you share the code that causes the problem?

Comment: did you add the menu items with a specific URL or are you getting the URL dynamically? because it looks like you may have added the menu items like this "nativemedialimited.com/mypage". That would cause this issue

Comment: i didn't add the menu with a specific url, in fact its not only the menu thats affected, the image src url and even the wp-admin url are affected

Comment: Its as if the url link works up to a certain point cos the site logo displays correctly, meaning the img src url is correct up to that point and everything afterwards goes wrong, just what i thought now, I've exhausted all possible reasons and solution i can think of.

Comment: I don't know if I can call this good news, but its a step. I moved the current content of my site into a folder (oldsite) to create space for a fresh install of wordpress directly into my remote server. Then I copied from the oldsite folder my theme, plugins, upload folder content, basically all useful item in the old wp-content folder, into my new wp-content folder. Then copied my old wp sql database to the new one, make sure the table prefix of the old and new are the same. and it worked. However new observation, i cannot login to my wp-admin dashboard, says i dont have permission.

Comment: I'm still curious tho as to why I had this whole problem initially, I'd like to know so I can avoid it next time

Comment: my permission challenge has bn resolved. it was from the change in the wp_ prefix when installing the new wp. I did 2 main things:

In my table, wp_usermeta, I changed all occurrences of wp_capabilities, wp_user_level, and wp_autosave_draft_ids to old prefix and
Then in table wp_options I changed wp_user_roles to old prefix

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: me 2! having the same issue. Any ideas on how to resolve this?^?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding an `http://` to your `WP_HOME` (Site Address (URL)) and `WP_SITEURL` (WordPress Address (URL)).

Comment: Thank you. It solve my problem. All links in database must include http:// and all links in wp_option.php file must NOT include http://

Answer (score 0):

All links in database must include http://

All links in wp_option.php file must NOT include http://

```
Open phpMyAdmin check 4 tables :
a) wp_blogs :
domain : www.funbeli.com
path : /

domain : http://www.2aek.com/funbuy (if wp files are in sub folder)
path : /funbuy/

b) wp_options :
siteurl : http://www.funbeli.com
home : http://www.funbeli.com

siteurl : http://www.2aek.com/funbuy (if wp files are in sub folder)
home : http://www.2aek.com/funbuy

click page 2 Then :
c) wp_site :
domain : http://www.funbeli.com
path : /

domain : http://www.2aek.com/funbuy (if wp files are in sub folder)
path : /funbuy/

d) wp_sitemeta :
siteurl : http://www.funbeli.com
siteurl : http://www.2aek.com/funbuy (if wp files are in sub folder)

Then edit wp-config file in wp folder :
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.funbeli.com');

define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.2aek.com');

define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/funbuy');
```